# How to pull object from component to html angular?

Tags: html, angular, mongodb

How can I pull an object from component to html angular?

Here is my component file code:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  authorID: string;
  authorData: any = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authorID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    console.log(this.authorID);
    this.getSingleAuthor();
  }

  getSingleAuthor() {
    let observable = this.httpService.getOneTask(this.authorID);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.authorData = data;
      console.log(this.authorData);
    });
  }
}
```

and here is my html code:

```
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" [routerLink]="['/write', 1]">Add Quote</button>
  <div class="info" *ngFor="let info of authorData">
    <p>Quote by {{info.name}}: </p>
    <table class="table border">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Quote</th>
          <th>Votes</th>
          <th>Action available</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  </div>
```

I tried to pull out author name from an object in component but it didnt work out. 
I tried to for loop and it worked but in my console it showed this error:

This is my author model:

```
  const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, "Name is Required"],
          minlength: [3, "Must be longer than 3 characters"]
      },
      author_quote: [{
          quote: {
              type: String,
              minlength: [3, "Must be longer than 3 characters"]
          },
          vote: Number
      }]
  })
```

> **Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'**

Comment: Isn't authorData an *object*, not an array? Why are you using ngFor, are you expecting to show multiple authors? If so, why is the default an object?

Comment: You have to show us the structure of the Object you wish to bind into the template. Please also reduce the code to the relevant lines instead all of your component...

Comment: I just want to get 1 author

Answer (score 0):

Ehy !

i assume that `authorData` is just an object of the kind:

```
{
  name
  age
  ...
}
```

So it's quite difficult that you need to iterate it with an `*ngFor` that is instead used for collections.

You should just ensure to render the portion of html that uses those data when they are ready:

1. Leave the `authorData` to `undefined` in your component: `authorData: any;`
2. Use an `*ngIf` in your template, so you will render that html when the author's data are available:

```
 <div *ngIf="authorData" class="info">
    <p>Quote by {{ authorData.name }}: </p>
    ...
 </div>
```

As alternative you can avoid to subscribe to the observable in the component and use an [async pipe approach](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/)

Comment: just add my author model into my question

Comment: just changed my code and it still not appear the name

Comment: mmm what `console.log(this.authorData)` print out ?

Comment: Happy to have been helpful !